# mv: 'path1/path2/filename1' and '/home/user1/dir1/path1/path2/filename1' are the same file

Tags: linux, find, command, mv

After using command:

```
find path1/ -iname 'file*[1234]' -exec mv -t /home/user1/dir1/path1/path2 {} \;
```

I got an error that those files are the same. The command finished successfully. The parent directory from where the search started is `path1/` and then as destination directory I put whole absolut path where I want the files moved. Why did this happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What `mv` is saying is that it makes no sense to move the particular file as moving it to the destination would write it back to itself.

You'll get the same thing if you try

```
mv file file
```

for any file called `file`.

As to *why* this happens:

You run `find` on the path `path1`.  I'm assuming that this is the same `path1` as in the absolute path `/home/user1/dir1/path1/path2`.

If you have files in `/home/user1/dir1/path1/path2` whose names matches the pattern that you use (these may have been moved there by an earlier invocation of your `find` command, or even by the *same* `find` due to the order of directory traversals that `find` makes), then these would be found by `find` (since `path2` is a subdirectory of `path1`). This would prompt `find` to try to execute an `mv` command that would move files from `path2` into `path2`.  This is what triggers the message (I'm hesitating to call it an actual "error").

To *avoid* looking into `path2` with `find`, you may do this:

```
find path1 \( -type d -path 'path1/path2' -prune \) -o -iname 'file*[1234]' -exec mv -t /home/user1/dir1/path1/path2 {} +
```

If the thing found is a directory (`-type d`) and if it's the pathname `path1/path2`, then prune it from the directory search tree that `find` builds while traversing the directories.  Otherwise, continue as before (almost, I changed the final `\;` to `+` to make `mv` take as many pathnames as possible at once).

Comment: I think the problem here is that there is a file matching the pattern in `.../path2/` **because** another such file was moved to that target directory during the find command and the target directory is traversed after the directory the file originated from. If you have `Afolder/file` but no `Bfolder/file` and you do `find -name file -exec mv -t Bfolder {} \;`, you get the error, but if you have a `Bfolder/file` and no `Afolder/file`, then you don't.

Comment: @StefanHamcke The error indicates that you are moving a file to itself. Not just that you are moving a file to another with the same name.  The actual inode is the same when this message is outputted.  Also, I _think_ you got your two examples mixed up.

Comment: I know. I'm referring to your sentence "*If you have files in* `/home/user1/dir1/path1/path2` ...". I think the OP did not originally have such files in the target dir, but they were moved there due to the command. Let me explain my example: Say you are in a dir with only `Afolder/` and `Bfolder/`  and also `Afolder/file` (regular file), but nothing else. Then you do not even need a `Bfolder/file` for the message to appear when you execute `find -name file -exec mv -t Bfolder {} \;`.

Comment: @StefanHamcke Ah, yes. It may depend on the order of traversal as well. If the destination directory is late in that order, files may already have started to accumulate there.

Comment: The above command will first descent into `Afolder/`, find the `file`, and move it to `Bfolder/`. After that, it will look into `Bfolder/` and stumble upon the file it did just move there.

Comment: @StefanHamcke Exactly. I just now added a short parenthesis about this.

Comment: Great, thanks for listening. I thought it might be worth adding :-)